# Virtual Yubikey

Tags: web-browser, account-security, multi-factor, yubikey

If reports are to be believed, Google and others are starting to force 2FA on user accounts starting late ~2021:
https://www.theverge.com/2021/10/5/22710421/google-security-2fa-inactive-account-management

I don't currently use 2FA on my accounts, and I'm reluctant to use SMS or USB Yubikey-like devices for 2FA but I'm interested in alternatives and still leveraging the 2FA security principles.  I'm also generally interested in understanding the technology used in 2FA authentication devices.

In my research, I've been looking at the FIDO alliance website:
https://fidoalliance.org/fido2/

Specifically this picture:
https://i0.wp.com/fidoalliance.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/FIDO2-Graphic-v3.jpg

It occurs to me that WebAuthn/FIDO2 2FA methods are just software APIs, and in just provide methods for interacting with your secret key to prove you have it.  Basically, a Yubikey is just a hardware container for your secret key that's somewhat protected, but easy to interact with.  Furthermore, the "client to authenticator protocol" is just a software API on the platform side.

Questions:

1. Can I write a pure software component (no hardware or USB key) that speaks the "client to authenticator protocol" and does the authentications in place of a Yubikey?  i.e. A virtual Yubikey implemented as a software application or device driver.
2. Do such components currently exist (preferably open source ones), and are there any you know about or can recommend?
3. Are there any WebAuthn/FIDO2 development libraries (preferably in Python) that let you write your own authenticator applications (virtual Yubikeys)?  i.e. A Python script that is functionally equivalent to a Yubikey in that it implements the API interface with the appropriate "client to authenticator protocol" to interact with your secret key.  Again, any references would be appreciated.

Ideally, I would like to write my own Python script that behaves as a virtual Yubikey.  So basically, I would go to Google, and log in, and when the browser asks for the 2FA step, I could then run a Python script (or application) that retrieves my secret key and completes the 2FA handshake in place of a Yubikey.  Am I misguided in my goals, or is this type of scheme possible with the existing 2FA schemes?

Comment: Why not simply use TOTP instead of a FIDO2 token? You can use any client tool that supports it (Google authenticator, Authy, MS authenticator, etc. on phone, Keyypass+KeeOTP2, Authy, etc. on your computer)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's directly related to your question but when you say "Basically, a Yubikey is just a hardware container for your secret key that's somewhat protected, but easy to interact with." I think you might be missing a key feature of such a device: if it's properly designed and implemented, you cannot export the private key.  A 'virtual' implementation will always be subject to the risk of private key exposure.

Comment: I don't understand the reason why you wouldn't want a yubikey-type device given the inherent limitations of doing this as software only.  Essentially you would get something roughly as secure as mTLS but with a bit more complexity.  If you are looking for help in how to do this, you might have better luck on Software Engineering or Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JimmyJames price can be a reason. In most countries a Yubikey cost as much as a latte, but where I live it cost almost half a month wages.

Comment: @ThoriumBR There's an NFC YubiKey for $25 which is more than a latte and only a small fraction of the average monthly wage in Brazil.  Are you saying they are more expensive there?  If so, that seems like an opportunity for arbitrage.

Comment: The hourly minimum wage in Brazil is around 1.13 USD (and the average is about 3 USD) at the time of this writing. So it would be around 1-3 days wages just for the key. Now add the shipping, and 60% taxes on top of the key plus shipping, plus a flat 2 USD fee for imported goods, and the price goes way up.

Comment: The Yubikey 5 NFC can be found for around 500-700 BRL, and the minimum monthly wage here is 1100 BRL. So not cheap at all.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Hmm.  For context how much would an entry-level computer cost?  This idea is pretty pointless if you don't own the computer.

Comment: Not sure why you specifically need a Yubikey, instead of more generic a FIDO U2F token. For the latter one there seems to be a 2 year old Python project which makes use of SoftHSM as the backend - see https://github.com/ellerh/softfido. Apart from that, Google explicitly supports that you use your phone for authentication.

Comment: @ThoriumBR At current exchange rates, that's at least twice the price ($45) of the same product advertised on their US site.  That level of gouging is unfortunate, if true.

Comment: Windows, Android and iOS have built-in platform authenticator so you don't need a hardware key. And for Linux there are also ways to simulate an authenticator https://blog.hansenpartnership.com/webauthn-in-linux-with-a-tpm-via-the-hid-gadget/

Answer (score 3):

Interesting idea.  I could see how an external python script could mimic what a Yubikey does, as far as generating and storing private keys that are used to authenticate with the various web sites that you would login to.

But, the challenge I see is: how would the python script insert itself in the flow between the browser and the server during authentication and registration?  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API for a diagram of the flow between the server and the browser during these steps (this is for WebAuthN, which is the [protocol that FIDO2 uses for registration and authentication](https://fidoalliance.org/fido2/fido2-web-authentication-webauthn/)).

As you can see, in both cases, the server sends a nonce to the browser, which the browser then passes to the Yubikey for it to sign using the private key stored on the Yubikey.  Then, the Yubikey passes the signature back to the browser, for it to send back to the server.

How would your external python script capture this nonce, sign it, then pass the signature back to the browser for it to send back to the server?

**EDIT**

Aside from the challenges of integrating the python script with the browser (see exchange between @JimmyJames and I in the comments below) - there is a more fundamental problem with this approach.  Every FIDO device has an `attestation keypair` burned into the device, which is specific to the make and model of the device.  The assertion keys generated by the device (which are used for authentication with sites) are signed with the attestation private key, so that the service that you are authenticating with knows what kind of device you are using.  See https://fidoalliance.org/fido-technotes-the-truth-about-attestation/ specifically the paragraph:

> With that context in mind, what is attestation? It is a key pair that
> is burned into the device during manufacturing time that is specific
> to a device model. For example, all YubiKey 4 devices would have the
> same attestation certificate; or all Samsung Galaxy S8’s would have
> the same attestation certificate. The attestation is specific to a
> device model and can be used to cryptographically prove that a user
> has a specific model of device when they register. When a user creates
> the new “credential key pair” mentioned above, the public key that is
> sent to the service is signed with the attestation private key. The
> service that is creating the new account for the user can verify that
> the “attestation signature” on the newly created public key came from
> the device.

So, if the service that you registering with only trusts certain devices, you would be out of luck, because your python script does not have the attestation private key for any of the trusted devices.

Comment: "How would your external python script capture this nonce, sign it, then pass the signature back to the browser for it to send back to the server?" What specific limitation are you seeing that would prevent this?

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm asking the opposite question, which is, "what mechanisms are in place for doing the?"

Comment: In order for the browser to interact with the device, it is using a software interface.  Why would we expect that software interface to not work with software?

Comment: @JimmyJames The Yubikey is a USB device.  So, the browser communicates with the Yubikey through the USB interface (i.e. a hardware interface).  So, either the browser would have to be modded in some way to communicate with the FIDO agent through some interface other than the USB interface - or somehow the the browser would need to communicate with the python script through the USB interface.  Are you thinking of some sort of virtual USB port that the python script listens on?  Perhaps that could work.

Comment: USB is one option, bluetooth, and authenticator apps are also options.  This kind of thing is a little outside of my wheelhouse but I don't see anything that would make this impossible.  I think the goal is questionable though.

Comment: @JimmyJames fair enough.  See the edit that I made to my answer, with an even more fundamental problem with this approach.

Comment: Good call.  That certainly changes things.  I doubt such a solution would be supported by FIDO.  It would seem to defeat some of the purpose by creating a weak option.

Comment: @JimmyJames Exactly.  It looks like they thought about this possibility, and came up with solution to mitigate it.

Comment: After reading the referenced URL, it's still not entirely clear to me why the 2FA process requires knowledge of the hardware vendor/device.  Conceptually, I would think that all the 2FA Yubikey method cares about is that I can prove I have access to the secret key I initially registered with.  Is this added feature of the protocol a marketing/business decision to control the monetization of the technology or a fundamental security concern?

Comment: @nehfan I think it's because some services want to ensure that you are using a FIDO device that meets certain requirements when it comes to securing the keys in the device.  The article that I referenced touches on this - see the paragraph starting with 'Some services though, such as those in the financial industry or the public sector, may be required to know more about the devices that are accessing their services'.

Answer (score 0):

Unless a Python implementation stores its secret in an HSM, it will necessarily be less secure.

Strong FIDO2 authentication solutions are superior because they are designed to make it very difficult to *silently steal the secrets*. You ask the key "Is this valid?" and it says "yes" or "no", with no programmatic way to retrieve the secret itself. Devices like YubiKeys function like an HSM in this way.

By contrast, most "soft" implementations - including any mobile TOTP implementations that don't store the secret in a hardware enclave - are subject to having the secret stolen and reused without detection  (or even kept in reserve until needed, months or years later). But to steal my YubiKey secrets, you have to pick my pocket (which I should notice relatively quickly). Well-designed physical keys are also resistant to side-channel attacks (that could be accomplished by stealing the key for a few hours and then putting it back).

[Virtual authenticators are available](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/webauthn/) - but are only intended for development, not for secure use.

Comment: How confident are you that Yubikeys and similar devices are properly designed and contain no back doors (intentional or otherwise), and no one is keeping a master list of the secret keys programmed in the devices?

Comment: I believe that managing private keys in my own one-off, proprietary, non-disclosed way is a potential added layer of security (with it's own pros and cons) and would avoid systematic flaws or backdoors in existing systems (phones, apps, Yubikeys, etc).  On the one hand, it might be less secure in general, but more secure for me in particular, as any attacker would have to target me individually, and have some knowledge about what I'm doing in order to steal my private keys.

Comment: As usual, YTMMV (Your Threat Model May Vary). :D Personally, I would rather rely on a standard - and implementations - that have been beaten on publicly, than on a roll-your-own approach (which has a demonstrably poor track record, including the classic "it is so strong that I can't break it, so no one else must be able to either" fallacy), as well as Kerckhoffs' Principle (assume the attacker knows everything except the secret).

Comment: @nehfan Perhaps [SoloKeys](https://solokeys.com/) may be an alternative for you?